# Which option is best to update in CakePHP2 With MySql

Tags: mysql, cakephp-2.0

```
$this->Model->id = $id;
$this->Model->saveField('field', 'value');
```

OR

```
$this->Model->set(array('fieldname' => 'value'));
$this->Model->save();
```

OR

```
$this->Model->updateAll(array("fieldName"=>"value"),array("fieldName"=>"condition"));
```

OR

```
$this->Model->save($this->request->data);
```

There are many option in cakephp to update data which also create confusion to choose one.

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1):

All have their own usage.please find my answers along with ur code.

1. When you wish to update one column for given id. you can use below code.
   $this->Model->id = $id;
   $this->Model->saveField('field', 'value');
2. It can be update multiple columns for given id. Here you added one field only. so, it will update only one column [affected to one row only].
   $this->Model->set(array('fieldname' => 'value'));
   $this->Model->save();
3. It will update field for multiple rows on which condition is satisfied.
   $this->Model->updateAll(array("fieldName"=>"value"),array("fieldName"=>"condition"));
4. Below line mainly used with insert statement, where all columns need to be saved. it may also used for update row too.

$this->Model->save($this->request->data);

I hope you find your answer.